# SharedPreferences - CastException: HashSet cannot be cast to TreeSet

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, classcastexception

I am trying to store `TreeSet` in the `SharedPreferences` using the following code:

```
        Set<String> chemicalValuesSet = new TreeSet<>();
        chemicalValuesSet.add("id: " + checkForNull(jsonChemicalValues.getString("id")));
        editor.putStringSet(SP_CHEMICAL_VALUES, chemicalValuesSet);
        editor.apply();
```

However, when I try to access that `TreeSet` I am getting casting error, as if this set is declared as a `HashSet`.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
            getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    TreeSet<String> chemicalValues =
            (TreeSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet(SP_CHEMICAL_VALUES, null);
```

I have no clue to solving this issue. In addition, when I started writing this part I was setting **chemicalValuesSet** as `HashSet` and retrieving without any problems, afterwards I decided to go with `TreeSet`s. That's why I have tried cleaning and restarting the project, but still same issues persists.

However, if I simply change type to `HashSet`
in the part where I retrieve this set, it works without complaining.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)

The "Return" explanations says that it throws class cast exception if key is not a set.

Comment: well, but it is a set.

Comment: uninstall the app and then reinstall again and check.

Comment: I have tried that as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply making false assumptions on how SharedPreferences and its editor works. The API never guarantees that the Set you get when calling `getStringSet()` is the same, or even the same implementation, as the one stored when calling `putStringSet()`. All it says is that you can pass a Set, and that you can get a Set.

If the API documentation says that it returns a Set, you should not assume that it's returning a TreeSet, or a HashSet. Only that it's returning a Set. If you absolutely need a TreeSet, then create one and copy the items from the returned Set to the TreeSet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast HashSet to TreeSet straight away.
Instead you can do either of the following to add all the items in the HashSet into TreeSet but keep in mind, the items added to the TreeSet will get sorted automatically.

```
// Passing the collection HashSet to TreeSet
HashSet<String> hashSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(SP_CHEMICAL_VALUES, null);
TreeSet<String> chemicalValues = new TreeSet<String>(hashSet);
```

or

```
// Adding all the values of the HashSet to TreeSet using addAll() API
// This will help to retain the values of TreeSet (if any)
TreeSet<String> chemicalValues = new TreeSet<String>();
...
HashSet<String> hashSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(SP_CHEMICAL_VALUES, null);
chemicalValues.addAll(hashSet);
```

Comment: It has no relation to the question I asked

Comment: Agree but the issue is because of the casting. The method SharedPreferences.getStringSet(...) returns Set<String> and you are trying to cast it to TreeSet<String> and that is what is causing the ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the returned set is a hash set:

```
 TreeSet<String> chemicalValues =
        (TreeSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet(SP_CHEMICAL_VALUES, null);
```

You can check this conclusion in source code in SharedPreferencesImpl.java

```
public Set<String> getStringSet(String key, Set<String> defValues) {
    synchronized (this) {
        awaitLoadedLocked();
        Set<String> v = (Set<String>) mMap.get(key);
        return v != null ? v : defValues;
    }
}
```

And you can also get the set type like this:

```
    chemicalValues.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

HashSet and TreeSet can not be interpreted to eachother.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: How did you conclude that it returns HashSet?